# Vue Datepicker Add Text/Value Each Day

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I wanted to add price/value on each day, the data `fetched` from the backend. It similar like Flight Datepicker on any websites, could Vuetify do that? or is there any Vue library that could achieve this?

[image: Date with Price]

Comment: Try to modify this as per your requirement. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#date-events

Comment: but that's only returning boolean/color/array of colors